# Why does using std::forward on an rvalue reference cause destruction of the object being referenced?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    ~A() {std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;}
};

void test(std::shared_ptr<A> ptr)
{
    std::cout << (ptr ? "not empty" : "empty") << std::endl;
}

void forwarder(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<A>)> f, std::shared_ptr<A>&& ptr)
{
    f(std::forward<std::shared_ptr<A>>(ptr));
    f(std::forward<std::shared_ptr<A>>(ptr));
}

void main()
{
    forwarder([](std::shared_ptr<A> ptr){ test(ptr); }, std::make_shared<A>());
}
```

The problem is in the `forwarder` function. After the first call to `test` the `shared_ptr` is destructed - along with the `A` object, obviously. So in the second call to `test` the pointer is already empty. I don't understand why that happens. `std::forward` implementation is trivial.
So, I have 2 questions:
1. How does `std::forward` cause the destruction of the rvalue object being passed to it? Which bit of code does that?
2. How can this C++ design decision be explained? Seems counter-intuitive to me that `ptr` is *not* out of scope yet but is already dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not destroyed, it is moved from. There is a big difference. Your use of `std::forward` is also totally incorrect, just FTR.

In this case, `std::forward<T>` is equivalent to `std::move`, which means that `ptr` is moved into the function. A move is like a copy operation but the state of the source object is *not* preserved. Therefore, unsurprisingly, later, it is empty because it has been moved from.

The argument to `f` is move-constructed from the rvalue returned by let's-call-it-`std::move(ptr)`.

Comment: How is it incorrect? Yes, it is equivalent to `std::move` in this case. I've created this test case based on other code where the reference is a "universal reference" rather than an rvalue reference, so I actually needed `forward` there.

Comment: There's no move happening in this code (that I can see). `std::move` doesn't do any moving, it just turns its argument into rvalue. Is it because the move constructor of `shared_ptr` is invoked here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: It's incorrect because `forward`'s only use case is in the case of universal references. Otherwise it is always superior to either pass the object as an lvalue or use `move` to move it. The argument of `f` is move-constructed from the rvalue.

Comment: So if the rvalue parameter was of my arbitrary class with no move constructor, instead of `shared_ptr` in this case, I would not observe this behavior as the move wouldn't occur?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: If you had a class which could not be moved, then the compiler would throw an error. Note that to do this, you would have to do something fairly extreme, like manually delete the copy constructor and move constructor. You can show this by replacing `std::shared_ptr` with `std::mutex`, I think, which is not movable from memory (but don't take my word for that).

Comment: Of course, if you meant "Copyable but no move constructor", like e.g. a C++03 class with a copy constructor, then you would also not observe this behaviour since move there would mean copy.

Comment: Yes, I meant copyable with no explicit move constructor, exactly. Thank you, I get it now.